# Windmeijer correction for Arellano-Bond Test in R package plm

Tags: r, plm

Let´s suppose I have a simple AR(1) panel data model I estimate with the pgmm command in R - data available :

```
library(plm)
library(Ecdat)
data(Airline)

reg.gmm = pgmm(output ~ lag(output, 1)| lag(output, 2:99), data= Airline, Robust=TRUE)
```

With `Robust=TRUE` I use the Windmeijer(2005) correction to the variance-covariance matrix. Now I want to test for second order autocorrelation using Arrelano-Bond:

```
mtest(reg.gmm, order = 2, vcov = reg.gmm$vcov)
```

Am I using the Windmeijer-corrected variance-covariance matrix, as I intend to? If not, how can I implement it? The documentation is quite tight-lipped on that topic. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: For me your code throws the following error: `Error in solve.default(crossprod(WX, t(crossprod(WX, A2)))) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.5216e-19` which is likely to be related to a problem concerning too many instruments in your sample data.

Comment: Since you are right about the documentation being quite limited on these types of concerns. I've found the book by the authors of the `plm` package to be a very helpful resource with much more detailed explanations and examples. It's called: "Panel Data Econometrics with R" by Yves Croissant and Giovanni Millo

Comment: There is no argument `Robust` to function `pgmm`. There is argument `robust` (note the non-capitalization of the letter `r`) to the `summary`method for pgmm objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the example with the `Airline` data throws an error which seems to be related to too many instruments in your GMM formula. If you are using different data which does not exhibit this problem you can use robust standard errors by using the `vcovHC` option in `mtest`. In your example the last call could then be:

```
mtest(reg.gmm, order = 2, vcov = vcovHC)
```